# what is '=0' after a section in linker script?

Tags: gcc, ld, linker-scripts

I think I knew this but forgot.
What does the '=0' sign after the section represent in linker script?

```
  .text :
  {
    *bootcode.o(boot)
    *vectors.o(vectors)
    *(.text) /* remainder of code */
  } =0
```

Comment: Including `=fill` in a section definition specifies the initial fill value for that section.   (=0 in your example).  ( https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_21.html )

Comment: thanks. you can make it your answer so that I can choose it. (couldn't find it on SO). BTW, not asked in the question, but does the linker(and compiler) insert the filling code for the region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including =fill in a section definition specifies the initial fill value for that section. (=0 in your example).  [manual](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_21.html)